# Problems with getting all responses within range

Tags: php, android

```
$latN = $_POST["latN"];
$latS = $_POST["latS"];
$longE = $_POST["longE"];
$longW = $_POST["longW"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM find WHERE lat <= latN AND lat >= latS
AND lng >= longW AND lng <= longE");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $lat, $long);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $lat, $long);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["lat"] = $lat;
    $response["long"] = $long;
}

print_r(json_encode($response));
```

I'm posting latN, latS, longE, longW to this page via android in the form of a string, I'm trying to find if there are any co-ordinates within the range of values I have given. I'm stumped and can't work out why it is all ways returning false. Any ideas?

Comment: does not make much sense for lat\long

Comment: The whole code doesn't make sense. Where do I even begin? 1- You define variables called `$latN` / `$latS` / `$longE` / `$longW` but don't use them anywhere. 2- Your `select` should probably have `?` instead of `latN` / `latS` / `longW` / `longE`. 3- The variables you are trying to bind don't exist.. 4- Even if you were using the correct variables, you'd be binding only 2 of them

Comment: No big deal, but you don't _have_ to `print_r` the response of `json_encode`, `echo` works fine too. Just as a side note ;)